# Returning JSON from EE module

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, expressionengine

I have created a module in Expression Engine (built with codeigniter framework).

I am using AJAX to submit a form, and want JSON responses returned.

The form is submitting correctly through AJAX and I have tested its adding to a db etc with different code.

As some test code for the JSON response I have set up the following:

```
public function placeItem() {

    $arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

    echo json_encode($arr);

}
```

with:

```
var options = { 
    success: update,
    url: 'http://www.domain.com/index.php?ACT=41'
}; 

function update(json) {
    alert(json);        
}

$('#wishlist-form').submit(function() { 
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 
    return false; 
});
```

This is rerturned:

```
"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/sites/d/domain.com/public_html/system/expressionengine/third_party/wishlist/mod.wishlist.php:77)</p>
<p>Filename: core/Common.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 408</p>

</div>
```

Line 77 is : echo json_encode($arr);

Firstly, I can't figure out why the PHP error is displaying.
Secondly, the JSON is returned in the alert, but if I try to do json.a for example it shows 'undefined'.

Comment: its looks like `EE` trying to send `header` information after your `echo` , if you really know what you are doing try `exit` instead of `echo` .

Answer (score 0):

hi try this to set json output

```
$this->output
    ->set_content_type('application/json')
    ->set_output(json_encode(array('foo' => 'bar')));
```